# How to create a persistence HSQL database?

Tags: hsqldb

I am new to HSQLDB and want to create a persistent database so that when opening HSQLDB, the already created tables with their contents exist. I read about HSQLDB in the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsqldb_db), but cannot find the information. My current `HSQLDB.bat` is the following:

```
cd %HSQLDB%
java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
REM java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server
REM java -classpath lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:hsqldb/demodb --dbname.0 testdb
```

When running the batch, the following dialogue opens:
[image]

Note that the URL filed contains `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.`.

After [OK], I call two scripts, one creating two tables, the other filling them with test data. But reopening HSQLDB does not read the tables with their data.

What is missing, what is wrong? A SHUTDOWN does not change anything. I also replaced `mem` with `file`, but could not make the database persistent. What did I oversee in the HSQLDB guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the drop-down list for `Type:` and select `HSQL Database Engine Standalone`, then edit the suggested URL to add your database file path such as `jdbc:hsqldb:file:///C:/Program Files/hsqldb-2.5.0/hsqldb/data/dbname` where the last part of the path is the name of the database files.

Absolute paths are preferred to avoid dependency on the directory in which you execute your batch.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the solution! See my minor edits in your answer!